# Replacing the paper on paper faced insulation

Tags: insulation

I recovered a bunch of unfaced insulation from various places in a building and would like to re-use them, but one would traditionally use paper faced insulation for many of the situations where I am going to install insulation.  Is there a way to get only the insulation paper?  What should I look for when searching for this material?

Answer (score 2):

No, cover it with plastic. Read about vapor barriers and whether or not you actually need one https://www.certainteed.com/insulation/resources/do-i-need-vapor-barrier/

---

You will notice that paper-faced insulation is not purely paper but it has a very thin layer of tar.

It serves two purposes:

1. Make the insulation stick to it so that it's one cohesive product
2. Act as a moisture barrier

Since there's no practical reason to recreate purpose #1 you only have to replicate purpose #2 and plastic wrap is the proper way.